# How to optimize a query with ORDER BY and FULLTEXT search?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table of 12 million lines.

```
CREATE TABLE `shingles` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `shingle` text NOT NULL,
     `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `used` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `stop` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `date` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `shingle` (`shingle`(255)) USING BTREE,
     KEY `count` (`id`),
     FULLTEXT KEY `shingle_fulltext` (`shingle`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11707635 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The following request is executed 20 sec

```
select `t1`.* from 
(select * from `shingles` 
where MATCH (shingle) AGAINST ('слово' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as t2 
inner join `shingles` as `t1` on `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
 order by `t1`.`count` desc limit 5
```

The more results in full-text search, the slower ...

How can I optimize? Without "order by" it works quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a subquery?  Doesn't this do the same thing?

```
select s.*
from shingles s
where match (s.shingle) against ('слово' in boolean mode)
order by s.count desc
limit 5;
```

That said, I don't think you are going to be able to significantly improve the performance of the query.